# Add own package dependencies to testTarget in package file

Tags: ios, swift, package, dependencies, fastlane

I'm developing a Swift app and using my own written packages in it. Everything works fine until I attempt to run tests via Fastlane. It throws an error saying, `Could not resolve package dependencies.` However, when I run the tests from Xcode, everything works smoothly.

If I run the tests from xCode, it works well.

**My package file:**

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Package_Name",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v17)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "Package_Name", targets: ["Package_Name"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "ConfigManager", path: "/Packages/ConfigManager"),
        .package(name: "NetworkManager", path: "/Packages/NetworkManager"),
        .package(name: "Notifications", path: "/Packages/Notifications")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Package_Name",
            dependencies: ["ConfigManager",
                           "NetworkManager",
                           "Notifications"],
            resources: [
                .process("Resources")
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "Package_NameTests",
            dependencies: ["Package_Name",
                           "ConfigManager",
                           "NetworkManager",
                           "Notifications"],
        resources: [
            .process("Resources")
        ]),
    ]
)
```

**Error message from fastlane:**

```
▸ xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
▸   the package at '/Packages/ConfigManager' cannot be accessed (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “ConfigManager” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Packages/ConfigManager, NSUserStringVariant=(
▸     Folder
▸ ), NSUnderlyingError=0x6000007aba20 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "fnfErr: File not found"}})
```

**lane in Fastfile**

```rb
lane :testPackage do
      puts 'Test ' + "Package_Name"
      scan(
          package_path: './Packages/' + "Package_Name",
          scheme: "Package_NameTests",
          devices: ["iPhone 15"],
          output_style: 'standard',
          output_directory: './fastlane/report/' + "Package_Name"  + '/',
          code_coverage: true,
          result_bundle: true,
          fail_build: false,
          clean: true,
          configuration: "Debug"
        )
    end
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Did you try to run scan with `Package_Name` scheme instead of `Package_NameTests` directly ? By default packages schemes are set up to be able to run their associated test target

Comment: @Gautier Thanks, I tried it directly with the package scheme name as well, but the results are the same :)

Comment: Shame :/ Otherwise if its suitable for your need, try the run_test lane instead ... this is what we use and it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Package_Name`'s dependencies are listed as absolute paths.

```
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "ConfigManager", path: "/Packages/ConfigManager"),
        .package(name: "NetworkManager", path: "/Packages/NetworkManager"),
        .package(name: "Notifications", path: "/Packages/Notifications")
    ],
```

This seems fishy to me. Maybe you meant for the dependencies location to be in a subfolder from the current `Package.swift` file? That would be `./Packages/...`

EDIT: Your comment indicates this answer was helpful and set you off on the right path. It sounds like, in your case, the dependent packages were located one directory higher from your working directory - `../ConfigManager`, `../NetworkManager`, and `../Notifications`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. 
I tried with `./Packages/` as well, the result is **almost** the same, but now the error message shows the full path and with this, I found my problem. The correct path is `../ConfigManager` and etc. 

After this, I had different error message, but that was because of depedencies. 

Thank you, and if you edit your answer to `../..` I'll accept it and give you the bounty :)